# Restore backup to different filegroup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, restore, filegroups

Using Sql Server 2008R2.

I have a backup of a filegroup. Is it possible to restore this to a different file group (possibly even on a different database)?

I have tried

```
RESTORE DATABASE my_database
   FILEGROUP = 'newFileGroup'
   FROM DISK='C:\restore\backupOfFileGroup.bak' 
   WITH RECOVERY
```

But get the following error:

```
Filegroup 'newFileGroup' cannot be restored because it does not exist in the backup set.
```

Comment: I believe that you have to restore the PRIMARY filegroup first.  My understanding is that the information on the filegroups in the database is maintained in the primary filegroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to restore this to a different file group

No.

> possibly even on a different database)

No.